# XSLT Processing of Excel Generated XML

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to go from **XML** generated in excel of the format:

```
...
    <Column255>1</Column255>
    <Column256>1</Column256>
</Row>
<Row>
    <Column1>1</Column1>
    <Column2>1</Column2>
    <Column3>1</Column3>
...
```

(This goes on for a long time)

Which ultimately maps a 256x256 grid into a format more like:

```
<map_point>    
   <x>0</x>
   <y>0</x>
   <value>1</value>
</map_point>

<map_point>    
   <x>0</x>
   <y>1</x>
   <value>1</value>
</map_point>
```

How should I do this?

My rough plan was to use `for-each` on each row and write that to the `x` co-ordinate then I get stumped by the column tags all being different, so I can't use `for-each` now to get my `y` co-ordinates out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use templates and pass the row number down in a parameter.  Something like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <map>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*/Row" />
    </map>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Row">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*[starts-with(local-name(), 'Column')]">
      <!-- position() will be 1 for the first row, 2 for the second ... -->
      <xsl:with-param name="rowNumber" select="position() - 1" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:param name="rowNumber" />
    <map_point>
      <x><xsl:value-of select="$rowNumber" /></x>
      <!-- for the column number, strip off the leading "Column" from the
           element name, convert the rest to a number and subtract 1 -->
      <y><xsl:value-of select="substring(local-name(), 7) - 1" /></y>
      <value><xsl:value-of select="." /></value>
    </map_point>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Ok, that's perfect. The next step in my programme is to write functions to describe my map based on what the value each map point takes. What is the best method of doing this? Is this able to be integrated within this same XSLT document, with different outputs, or does my results from this XSLT need to be put through a new programme?

For context, the plan is to extend this with vector fields for each point to describe motion of particles in space based on gravity. Values representing planets/stars etc.